# Separate login for user / administrators using mongodb

Tags: database-design, mongodb, database-recommendation

I have 2 separate groups of users on my website. One is user and the other one is admin.  Currently I put them in 2 different collections **user** and **admin** and login respectively.  My questions is:

1. Mongodb generates _id automatically for both **user** and the **admin** collection.  Since they're in 2 different collections chances are one day you created one user and one admin with the same _id right?  So it seems the only way is to check all documents in both dbs and make sure your newly created user (or admin) does not have repeated _id right?  Is there something I can do natively in mongodb to make this happen without checking?
2. I can also put all users and admins in one collection.  This way I don't have a problem but I am not sure if I should do this.

p.s: because I have a table keeping track of user / admin balances so I certainly don't want the _id to repeat
p.s2: the db is taking longer and longer to query.  Also my ORM creates user instances and generated _id automatically for me.  I am not sure if I should just generate an _id and create it this way...

Any comments are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have two collections, that will give you headache.

Have a user collection which has admin and regular users.  You can then query users as a whole or look for a given type only. So if you are looking for user id x you don't have two search two collections.

As for the question on duplicate ids with 2 collections, it simply depends how the ids are generated.  You say your ORM does it... so you will need to check the doc on how it does it.

Comment: got it. about 1 it is that I am dealing with transactions and I don't want things like collide id to happen. Although I know it probably wouldn't. Also I thought when I separate the collection I can do map-reduce more efficiently on some scenarios but maybe I really shouldn't worry about this kind of things. But I agree what you said is better!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. About _id generation, as long as you don't specify _id explicitly, Mongo would handle the id for you. It generates different nonce for different collection. So you should not need to worry about duplicated _id across different collection. Reference [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).
2. I agree with other answer, use same collection and put an extra field to differentiate regular user and admin